# How to have a specific enum case which is bound to a protocol

Tags: swift, generics, enums

Here a simple example of what I want:

```swift
protocol P: Equatable {}

enum A: P {}
enum B: P {}

enum Foo {
  case 1
  case 2
  case test(P)
}
```

In the Foo enumeration, the third case `test` in `Foo` enum is what I would like.
In other words, I want to have a type which conforms to the protocol P.
It is not possible to use directly P which is a protocol.
For instance, the case `test` could be an enum of the type A or B.

Indeed, I could have:

```
enum Foo<T: P> {
  case 1
  case 2
  case test(T)
}
```

However, it will be used only for the third case.
Hence, it will be annoying to have to give a type if I do not need it.

Do you have any suggestions for solving this problem ?

-- Edit --

Indeed, the last version was working.
I just added that the protocol P conforms to the protocol `Equatable`.
Now, I get the same issue with the following error:
"Protocol 'P' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements".

I think I understand why it is a problem, cause Swift suppose that I can compare two objects of different types.
However, it will not be possible in my implementation.

Comment: Does your protocol `P` have an associated type? With your current example, `Foo` compiles just fine without being generic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I modified my answer to be more in line with what I have.
I do not have associated types.

Comment: @damdamo, but `Equatable` does have a reference to `Self`, and your protocol `P` inherits from `Equatable`, the effect of which is the same as if `P` had an associated type. I think you'd need to show a bit more than pure conceptual example - i.e. why do you need to use a protocol here and what do you intend to do with them

Comment: @NewDev The only way to solve my problem is to use: `enum Foo<T: P>` ?

Comment: @damdamo, it would solve the compile error, yeah.. but what are you trying to achieve. Why is conformance to Equatable is what you want?

Comment: @NewDev I have some enumerations which are all `Equatable`.
The logic would be that all of my enumerations that I gathered inside `Foo` are equatable.
I created a protocol `P` which specifies conditions for all of my declared enumerations (e.g.: Having some methods...)
Moreover, all of my enumerations are `Equatable`, I want to be able to compare them to know if there are equals.
I thought it was more elegant to add the protocol conformance on the protocol `P`.
It is true that I can remove `Equatable` from the protocol and everything work.
I can add `Equatable` on each enumeration.

Comment: @damdamo, sure, you can say that conformance to `P` also requires conformance to `Equatable`, if that's what you need. It basically says that some type `Bar: P`, can do `Bar() == Bar()`. But what does it mean for `Foo` (even if it magically compiled)? If you say that you'd never compare different types, then a `Foo` that has a `A` and a `Foo` that has a `B` value as a `test` case, are different - just like `enum Foo<T: P>` are different from each concrete implementation.